# laravel view pdf file with ajax method

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am implementing a post method with Ajax and I have to get a PDF output after this post process.

After post method i get certain data and print this data in PDF.

When I post with ajax, I need to output a pdf. in console it gives me output like this:
[image]
When I run these codes with ajax, there is no problem, but when I run them with ajax, I can't get the result I want.

What should I do exactly? Where am I missing?

And this is my codes
**Route**

```
Route::post('/label',[HomeController::class,'createLabel'])->name('create-label')->middleware('auth');
```

**Controller:**

```
$dompdf = new PDF();
$dompdf = PDF::loadView('myPDF', $data);
$customPaper = array(0, 0, 288.64, 419.53);
$dompdf->setPaper($customPaper, 'portrait');
$content = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('label2.pdf', $content);
$pdf = new \Clegginabox\PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
$data = base64_decode($r->labelData);
file_put_contents('label1.pdf',$data);
$pdf->addPDF('label1.pdf', 'all');
$pdf->addPDF('label2.pdf', 'all');
$pdf->merge('browser', 'LABEL'.$order->orderNumber.'.pdf', 'P');
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
            url:"{{route('create-label')}}",
            type:"post",
            data:{
              orderId:orderId,
              _token:'{{ csrf_token() }}'
            },
            success:function(response){
              console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(response) { 
              console.log(response);
              });
            }  
        });
```

Comment: just for test @Donkarnash

Comment: Do you tried to save the pdf in the server part and download it by url by js ?